# Emulator - draw: Could not run program

Tags: android, android-emulator

Emulator works fine but while interacting after a time (maybe 20-30 min.) **it's not responding** and this log 'draw: Could not run program' appears. How can i deal with it ?

[image]

And list goes...

[image]

The emulator after error

[image]